# C# GUI Editable DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

What conditions must be satisfied for a `DataGridView` to be editable by a user through **GUI**? such as pressing `F2` for modifying, selecting a row for deletion, or adding a new row?

When I bind `DataGridView.DataSource` to a local collection object such as `List<T>`, I am able to perform all three actions.

When I bind `DataGridView.DataSource` to a `DataTable` or `DataView`, I am also able to do all three graphically.

But when I bind `DataGridView.DataSource` to `DbSet<T>.ToList<T>()` or `DbSet<T>.ToArray<T>()`(`Entity Framework`), I can only modify non primary key values of existing rows, even though I have enabled *delete* and *add* function through DataGridView wizard, and specifically set `AllowUserToAddRows` and `AllowUserToDeleteRows` to `true`. When run, the application won't display the **star** symbol indicating the ability to add a new row. Deleting a row is not possible either.

The data, however, displays correctly.

So, I am puzzled. What characteristics of the above mentioned data sources could have caused the different behaviors in GUI?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataGridView` control allows user to add row if both `AllowUserToAddRow` is set to true and the underlying data source implemented [`IBindingList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist(v=vs.110).aspx) returning `AllowNew` as true. Similar rules for remove as well.

You can take a look at [`AllowUserToAddRowsInternal`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridView.cs,734) and [`AllowUserToDeleteRowsInternal`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridView.cs,788) internal methods' source code.

As a conclusion, these are allowed operations based on data source:

- `List<T>`: Edit
- `BindingList<T>`: Add, Edit, Delete (For Add, `T` should have parameterless constructor)
- `Array`: Edit
- `DataTable`: Add, Edit, Delete
- `BindingSource`: Depends to the underlying data source of the `BindingSource`. If it's an implementation of `IBindingList` it asks from it, otherwise if the list is not `FixedSize` then all operation are allowed, otherwise, just edit is allowed. So for example if you set a `List<T>` as data source of a binding source and then set the binding source as data source of data grid view, then the list will be allowed for all operation.
- `IBindingList`: Asks from implementation.

Comment: thanks. For data source such as List<T> which is not an implementation of IBindingList at all, does that mean that AllowUserToAddRows or AllowUserToDeleteRows property alone is sufficient to determine whether adding or deleting rows is allowed? List<T> seems to support Add also in addition to Edit and Delete in your conclusion. Thanks

Comment: The only way to edit a `List<T>` in `DataGridView` is using a `BindingSource`. Based on the binding source rules, if you set the `List<T>` as data source of `BindingSource` and then set the `BindingSource` as data source of `DataGridView`, then you can *Add*, *Edit* and *Delete* items of `List<T>`.

Comment: In addition to above conditions to support *Add*, don't forget to have public parameter-less constructor (which normally you have in a plain class.)

Comment: thanks so much for your help.  But still confused. I understand your reasoning about List<T>'s Add operation not being supported, but since it doesn't implement IBindingList.AllowRemove either, why is Delete operation allowed?

Comment: And similarly, DataTable is no implementation of IBindingList either. But it supports all three operations?

Comment: I am referring to List<T> being a direct data source of a DataGridView. Thanks.

Comment: Oops, that's my mistake. The same rules applies for Delete as well, so I should correct my comments: `List<T>`: *Edit*

Comment: In fact the control itself also describe some rules for us: *Rows cannot be programmatically removed unless the DataGridView is data-bound to an IBindingList that supports change notification and allows deletion.*

Comment: I extracted the rules by reading source code of the `DataGridView` and internal source codes related to it.

Comment: When working with Entity Framework, try to bind to `Local` property of the `EntitySet`. It's a `BindingList` in fact.

Comment: Thanks. :) However, how about the DataTable? DataTable is not an implementation of IBindingList. Yet it is allowed for all three implementation when it is a direct data source of a DataGridView?

Comment: You're welcome. When you bind datagridview to datatable, on fact it binds to its default view which is a dataview which implements the interface.

Comment: Reza, thank you so much. I have a much better understanding now. You are great.

Answer (score 0):

1. Fill dataTable and use it as a bining source to datagridview

1.1 Do changes in datagridview...

```
public void DAL_UpdateStudentsTable(DataTable table) //DAL represents 3-tyer architecture (so data access layer)
{
  using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString))
  {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
      cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE Students SET " +
                "StudentID = @id, " +
                "FirstName = @first, " +
                "LastName = @last, " +
                "Birthday = @birthday, " +
                "PersonalNo = @personal " +
                "WHERE StudentID = @oldId";
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "StudentID");
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@first", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "FirstName");
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@last", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "LastName");
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@birthday", SqlDbType.DateTime, 1, "Birthday");
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@personal", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "PersonalNo");
      SqlParameter param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@oldId", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "StudentID");
      param.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
      cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
      using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
      {
        da.UpdateCommand = cmd;
        da.Update(table);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. When you want to update database simply create an Update command and do it like what you see above.